# I am using Crystal Reports and trying to break out a field into 3 separate fields to print

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports and trying to break out a field into 3 separate fields to print. example of field is 112-111-5  but i need to print 3 separate fields  112   111   5.

Comment: It seems easy to find the answer with a search engine. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string by using the function `split("112-111-5", "-")` in a formula and put it in an array for example.

If you just want to get rid of the dashes you can do `Replace(112-111-5, "-", " ")` in a formula.